# concatenating two python lists together to create a log file

Tags: python, list

I have a program where I calculate some values, and instead of having 30 print statements I want to make the code neater and easier to maintain.

store the description and the actual value in two separate lists and concatenate them into a log file at the end of the program to print.

I'll provide an example using two lists:

```
description = ["name","phone","height"]
value = ["john","0431599430","160"]
```

I want to print:

```
name: john
phone: 0431....
height: 160
```

My code:

```
for i in value:
    d = description(i);
    v = value(i);
    add = str(d) + ": " + str(v);
    print add
```

**Update -- Thanks all for responses, I've since also seen this, Another possible solution:**

```
d = ["digit","code","symbol"]
v = [1,2,3]

for i in range(len(d)):
    print (d[i],v[i])
```

Which when it is printed looks like this:

```
('digit', 1)
('code', 2)
('symbol', 3)
```

**I can remove the the () and the '' from this using replace, so it looks like below, but what causes the two lists to be printed with that extra stuff () '' around it in the first place is what I don't understand?**

```
digit 1
code 2
symbol 3
```

Comment: You can also use a `dict` instead of two separate lists.

Comment: Hi George thanks for your answer I think a dict might be my best option, eventually I want to get the data into an excel spreadsheet. By using a dict I could use the pandas DataframeFromDict method. Can you give an example of how these two lists could be a dictionary given the syntax I have written under MY CODE doesn't work to grab the value out of each list (which I could then put into a dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

Use `zip` to combine the two lists. One possibility:

```
for f, v in zip(description, value):
    print "{0}: {1}".format(f, v)
```

Comment: I think this is works too, but when it prints out the data, it is shown with backets () and quotation marks'name', is there any way to get rid of these using this example, so

Comment: The code above will print a string containing the values from the list. The code you added to your question prints a tuple that contains strings, which is why it displays the parentheses and the quoted name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `zip`:

```
d = ["name","phone","height"]
v = ["john","0431599430","160"]

print '\n'.join(': '.join(i) for i in zip(d,v))

[OUTPUT]
name: john
phone: 0431599430
height: 160
```